# CodeIgniter htaccess from folder to root

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

There are a number of people who have bookmarked a site that had a URL like this:    http://www.domain.com/map/.

This morning we changed the content that was in the map folder to the root. I have been trying to write an htaccess for codeigniter to eliminate the index.php and redirect from the map folder to the root.

I have not been successful

I have this so far -- conn is my default controller

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(conn(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
rewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com/map/
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^map/$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The rule above will take all hits to `http://www.example.com/map/` and redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) them to the root folder: `http://www.domain.com/`.

It will work for THAT URL ONLY (which means that hit to `http://www.example.com/map/somepage` will NOT be redirected. If you need to redirect ALL URLS in `/map/` folder to a root, then remove `$` from that rule.

**P.S.**
Keep in mind that order of rewrite rules matters, so place this rule above your CodeIgniter rewrite rules (if any) -- possibly just below `RewriteBase` one.

Comment: Is there anything else I have to do? I added the rule as suggested (`RewriteRule ^map/ http://www.myownapartment.com/ [R=301,L]`) right under RewriteBase / and still get 404 Not Found.

Comment: by the way, I added a controller by the name of "map.php" with an index function to redirect to "conn/index" but that isn't helping either ... and also there is NO folder named map in the site

Comment: @jgravois Can you please update your question with current .htaccess (with my rule there). Also could you please confirm which URL you are trying **exactly**. In Any case -- try adding this line on very top: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`

Comment: @jgravois Could you please tell what exactly you did to make it work (Options line .. or you were requesting wrong URL). Thnx